# What does it mean for a function of two arguments $f: [0, \infty) \times M \to M$ to be continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, definition

Suppose we have a metric space $(M,d)$

Let $f: [0, \infty) \times M \to M$.

What does it mean for $f$ to be continuous?

Here are some suggestions:

1. $f$ is continuous if for every open set $V \subseteq   M$ ,
   $f^{-1}(V)$ is open in the product topolgy of $[0 , \infty) \times
   M$, where the product topology is the topology generated by the natural topology on $[0, \infty)$ and the metric topology on $M$.
2. $f$ is continuous if for all sequences $(t_k, x_k) \to (t,x) $, $f(t_k,x_k)$ converges to $f(t,x) \in M$
3. $f$ is continuous if for all $(t,x) \in [0 \times \infty) \times M$, and for all $\epsilon >0$, there exists a $\delta >0$, such that if $(t',x') \in [0, \infty) \times M$ whenever $d((t,x), (t',x')) < \delta \implies  d(f(t,x), f(t',x')) < \epsilon$

Can someone check my definition? And are these conditions equivalent?

Note: the last definition is messed up, I just noticed $d((t,x), (t',x'))$ doesn't make sense.

Comment: Topological, sequence and $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definitions of continuity are always equivalent, if everything is established with the same metric across the 3 definitions.  This question doesn't really seem to have to do with the product space.  Perhaps you want to ask: what are different topologies on a product space?

Comment: Yes, they are equivalent. In the point 2), for the sake of completeness, you might want to add in which topology those sequences are convergent

Comment: The definitions look correct.   They are equivalent.   There are other possible definitions, such as, the preimage of every closed set is closed.   It can also be done with nets (or filters), or the closure operator.

Comment: Your last definition in (3) can be "saved" and made sensible. Define the distance between $(t, x)$ and $(t', x'))$ in the product space $[0, \infty) \times M$ to be $D\big((t,x), (t', x')\big) = \max\big(|t' - t|, d(x, x')\big)$. You can check this is a metric and in fact a metric that induces the product topology on $[0, \infty) \times M$.

Comment: @ZeroXLR Thanks

Comment: @NajKamp Yes, I didn't define convergence in what sense

Comment: @Dzoooks Yes, I was not sure which topology should I equip on $[0, \infty) \times M$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All 3 are equivalent, provided you take a correct metric on $[0,\infty) \times M$. We could take $D((t_1,x_1), (t_2,x_2)) = \max(|t_1 - t_2|, d(x_1,x_2))$ and that metric $D$ induces the product topology on $[0,\infty) \times M$.

So the reformulated version of 3. would be:

> $f$ is continuous if for all $(t,x) \in [0 \times \infty) \times M$, and for all $\epsilon >0$, there exists a $\delta >0$, such that if $(t',x') \in [0, \infty) \times M$ whenever $(|t-t'| < \delta \land d(x,x') < \delta) \implies  d(f(t,x), f(t',x')) < \epsilon$

because $\max(a,b) < \delta$ iff $a < \delta \land b < \delta$. We could also have used a Euclidean combination like $D((t_1,x_1), (t_2,x_2)) = \sqrt{(t_1-t_2)^2 + d(x_1,x_2)^2}$ or $D((t_1,x_1), (t_2,x_2))= |t_1 + t_2| + d(x_1,x_2)$, but the $\max$-variant gives the "nicest" reformulation IMHO.

You're basically restating 1. in two other guises: epsilon-delta in 3 and sequentially in 2. So I'd say 1. is the correct interpretation of the question in 
the title (taking the product topology and the default topology on $[0,\infty)$) and by standard facts 2. and 3. are equivalent in the metric setting that you're in.